How can I get the the unrecognized Token in an ANTLRErrorListener for a Lexer?
I have a lexer, generated with ANTLR. What I try to achive is to handle an error during lexing in case of an not recognized token.
How can I get only the character causing this error?

lexer.addErrorListener(new ANTLRErrorListener() {
  @Override
  public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer,  
                          Object offendingSymbol, int line,
                          int charPositionInLine, String msg,
                          RecognitionException e) {

  }

  // ....
}


The given message msg contains a message and the character, but I would like to have the character only to generated a better message for the users of my code.

From the line and column passed to syntaxError(), you can compute the index of the offending character with the contents of the file, then get the character using getText(). But, I don't think there's a function in the API to convert line/column into an index in the file. You'll probably have to write that yourself. And, if you have to do that, you may as well write a getOffendingChar(int line, int column).

You can get the offending character like this:
lexer.addErrorListener(new ANTLRErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer,
                            Object offendingSymbol, int line,
                            int charPositionInLine, String msg,
                            RecognitionException e) {

        int index = recognizer.getInputStream().index();
        String text = lexer.getInputStream().getText(Interval.of(index, index));

        throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Don't know how to handle '%s'", text));
    }

    // ...
});

